# How do I get the last message sent by a specific user?

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently running discord.js v13 and I'm trying to find a way of finding the last message sent by a specific user. So far, I've come up with the idea of iterating on an array of user IDs, then iterating on each channel and comparing each timestamp with the pervious timestamp found until it finds the latest one and stores it. However, this doesn't seem to work and I just keep getting today's date for ALL the users even though the majority of them haven't sent a message today.

My Code:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < array_of_users.length; i++) {
        for (const channel of message.guild.channels.cache.values()) {
            if (channel.isText()) {
                let messages = await channel.messages.fetch().catch(e => console.log(e));
                messages.each((msg) => {
                    if (msg.author.id === array_of_users[i]) {           
                        if(x == 0) {
                            old_date = new Date(msg.createdTimestamp).toDateString();
                            snowflakes.push(old_date);
                            x += 1;
                        } else {
                            var new_date = new Date(msg.createdTimestamp).toDateString();
                            let splitOld = old_date.split(" ");
                            let splitNew = new_date.split(" ");
                            if(parseInt(splitNew[3]) >= parseInt(splitOld[3])) {
                                year = splitNew[3];
                                if(getMonthInt(splitNew[1]) >= getMonthInt(splitOld[1]) ) {
                                    monthC = splitNew[1];
                                    if(getDayInt(splitNew[2]) >= getDayInt(splitOld[2])) {
                                        dayNum = splitNew[2];
                                    } else {
                                        dayNum = splitOld[2];
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    monthC = splitOld[1];
                                    dayNum = splitOld[2];
                                }
                            } else {
                                year = splitOld[3];
                                dayNum = splitOld[2];
                                monthC = splitOld[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        console.log(`${monthC}-${dayNum}-${year}`); 
    }
```

The code above I've written to sort the dates and get the latest one, However something is wrong that it keeps getting the latest date and sometimes even future dates that haven't occurred yet. I can't seem to find the issue but I am speculating that it is originating around the `if (msg.author.id === array_of_users[i])` area.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830873/discord-js-how-do-i-use-sort-to-sort-a-collection-of-fetched-messages

Comment: The sort command works and all but it only tells me how to sort messages for a single channel. I looped it to make it work on multiple channels, But still this doesn't give me the latest date for each user in all the channels combined, rather it just sorts the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to find a way of finding the last message sent by a specific user.

Discord.JS provides no 'built in' way of doing this. The best you can do is by grabbing their messages and comparing each of them to one another until you've exhausted your options and are left with the optimal result. So your approach is (more or less) correct, although your implementation does have some function errors that are throwing you off.

> So far, I've come up with the idea of iterating on an array of user IDs, then iterating on each channel and comparing each timestamp with the pervious timestamp found until it finds the latest one and stores it.

If you only are only looking for the most recent message for a specific User, then it is redundant to be dealing with an Array of Users altogether.

> However, this doesn't seem to work and I just keep getting today's date for ALL the users even though the majority of them haven't sent a message today.

There are a number of errors in your approach which could be causing this. Here's a quick few of the more generalized / lack-of-experience related errors in your solution for you to work on:

- The `else` block where you're comparing days split up from timestamps is super convoluted. Why not just use the `createdTimestamp` value from the Message instance itself, then reconstruct the whole `monthC-dayNum-year` thing again later on using that if you need to?
- You're likely going to be hitting Discord's Rate limits (rather frequently) with your script as-is. To put it in perspective, you're basically spamming requests to their API for the next X messages in channels [A, B, ...ZA, ZB] repeatedly. You can optimize this a lot by making logical inferences as to when you can safely 'exclude' a Channel from your search (e.g. if the most recent message you've found in channel X was created on Jun 18 2022, and most recent message found in channel Y was created on Mar 13 2022, you can safely avoid asking Discord for more Messages for channel Y, as it won't have any information relevant to your use case). Writing some additional logic here will pay dividends to you both in how quickly your function can execute, and how frustrating it is to debug once Discord gets upset with you for your small-scale DDOS attack against them.

If I was to solve this problem, the way I would do it would be to employ the following logic:

1. Given GuildMember X, grab all the Channels in the Guild they belong to.
2. Filter those Channels so you're only working on TextChannels.
3. Recursively iterate through those Channels, keeping track of the 'latest message' found belonging to GuildMember X in that Channel (when/if found). Whenever you find a new message belonging to GuildMember X in Channel Y, check if that beats the most recent message found across the entire set thus far. If so, update the best message for the set accordingly. Continually filter the Channels you're working with as you go to exclude Channels that logically cannot hold anything relevant to your search-- any time you finish a recursion, you can go back over the set of Channels and look for any one where the 'best message' in that channel does not beat the current best message. Since you're fetching 'backwards in time' (asking Discord for progressively older and older messages as you continue to recurse), any time the best message in a given channel does not beat the best message across the entire set, you can be certain that the channel does not hold the droids that you are looking for. You're only going to be fetching even older messages than the earliest one already fetched if you continue to look in that Channel, which makes that Channel irrelevant to you at that point.

Lucky for you, I had some time to kill while travelling today, and for whatever reason trying to find an optimal solution to your problem interested me enough to give it a proper shot. The tips I wrote above should help you understand the code below, and if not, leave a comment and maybe I can help you out. Here's how I would solve your problem, while paying attention to logical exclusion and avoiding doing unnecessary work / API calls.

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-surf-50vpmf?file=/index.js

Comment: This is an amazing description explaining the issue I've faced and helped me understood more than enough. Thank you very much for your time and effort and I wish you success :)

Comment: However, I do have a question, When running your code I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')` in the line `await member.guild.channels` I noticed that I am meant to pass a GuildMember Object, So instead of just passing in the parameters `"1234567890"` for example, I changed it to `client.users.cache.get("1234567890")`. So I'd use the function like this: `var latest = await getLatestGuildMessageFor(client.users.cache.get("1234567890"));`. However, I'm still getting the same issue. Any idea on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Also, I wanted to also mention, that I have tried changing the code using your same logic a day ago after I've posted this thread. And, I did mange to get something that works. However, For some reason in this code, most of the time it keeps giving this error for no reason: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createdTimestamp' of undefined` which results it in not having the most accurate date, And Im not sure why it does this so i resulted in replacing it with the current date. Here is a link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-moore-dt16u6?file=/index.js

Comment: Ok, So I've changed `member.guild.channels` to `guild.channels` since Member does not contain a `guild` but nothing is being returned now, So I'm not sure what could be the issue since the only issue was with that line. I'm using these to lines to print the object, `var latest = await getLatestGuildMessageFor(client.users.cache.get("1234567890"));` and `console.log(latest);` I'm getting no output or error

Comment: > TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
This would be caused due to the GuildMember passed to the 'outer function' not having a Guild attached to it for some reason. Perhaps you were passing a User to it, or something like that. That line was used to grab the Channels of a Guild-- the `undefined` bit is telling me that you were not passing in a GuildMember to the Function. Seems like you figured that on your own, though.

Comment: > So I'd use the function like this: var latest = await getLatestGuildMessageFor(client.users.cache.get("1234567890"));. However, I'm still getting the same issue. Any idea on how this can be fixed?

client.users is a cache of Discord **User** Instances. The function expects a Discord **GuildMember** Instance. The fix for this behavior would be to either (A) modify the function to accept a User and a Guild (then find the GuildMember Instance from `guild.members.fetch(user.id)`), or to simply pass in a GuildMember to begin with.

Comment: So, wherever you are calling this function, lets say that you have a Guild Object and an ID of a User (but no GuildMember). I would do this:

```
const guildId = `some-guild-id`
const userId = `some-user-id`


const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId)
if (!guild) throw new Error(`No guild w/ ID: ${guildId}`)

const guildMember = await guild.members.fetch(userId)
if (!guildMember) throw new Error(`No guild member w/ ID: ${userId} in Guild ID: ${guildId}`)

const latestMessage = await getLatestGuildMessageFor(guildMember)
```

Comment: Sorry my comments aren't formatting right. I'm just going to make a few changes and post a new CodeSandbox for you in a moment. Hang tight

Comment: Ok so I did it exactly how you mentioned it. Although the error is gone now, I'm not getting any output. I'm trying to `console.log(latestMessage)` however, nothing is being printed in the console, not even an error. I was thinking this may have been a partial or intent issue. But I have all my partials and intents sorted. `partials:["CHANNEL"] intents: [GUILDS, GUILD_MESSAGES, GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, GUILD_MEMBERS, GUILD_PRESENCES, DIRECT_MESSAGES, DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING, GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING]});` Obviously before each intent there is a `discord.Intents.FLAGS`, because not enough chars

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, I'm not exporting the function like you are, I just have it in the same file, So basically I copied everything after the `module.exports =` and placed it within my module exports. So it's like a standalone function basically, same way it's done in the code sandbox link I sent you. I don't think it makes any difference, But i just wanted to let you know incase its of any significance

Comment: @jiyahok320 I cleaned up my code a bit and decided to just publish it as an NPM package, in case anyone ever stumbles upon a need for this sort of thing. You can [find the package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-find-latest-msg-in-guild). If you need more help with this, [make an Issue on the package's repository](https://github.com/jamesonknutson/discord-find-latest-msg-in-guild/issues) instead of replying here-- the formatting is messing me up 